In a JSP file use a form to call a method in a java file to create and then download a a csv file for the user
Having a hard time figuring out how to get my JSP file to trigger a method in my java while using a form. The method sends a query to a db, I want to take the result set from that query and turn in into a csv file and then send it back to the user and have it downloaded by their browser.
jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form Example</h1>
    <form action="class/method" method="post">
        
        <input type="submit" name="Download">
       
    </form>
</body>
</html> 

Java
public class Class{

  public void Method()

  String sql="select * from table"

  connectionmanger cm=server.getcm();

  connection con=null;

  preparedstatment statment=null;

  resultset rs=null

  try{

  con=cm.allocateconnection();
  statmen=con.preparestatment(sql);
  rs=statment.excutequery();

  }

  catch{

  error handling stuff
}

 finally{

 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
Boolean includeHeaders = true;

java.sql.ResultSet myResultSet = rs

writer.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);

writer.close();
cm.closestatment(statment);
cm.closeresultset(rs);
cm.delalocateconnection(con);
}
}


Are you using servlet to handle the requests? if yes then could you please make sure that your action attribute points to proper servlet's  doPost method(as form's method is POST).
I have modified your code & corrected some things. Please try below code & let me know how it goes.
JSP:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form Example</h1>
    <form action="yourServlet/URL" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

SERVLET(JAVA):
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

@WebServlet("/yourServlet/URL")
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String sql = "select * from table";
        ConnectionManager cm = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            con = cm.allocateConnection();
            statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();

            // Set response headers to prompt download
            response.setContentType("application/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"yourfile.csv\"");

            // Create CSV writer
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer);

            // Write CSV header
            csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}); // Replace with your actual column names

            // Write data rows
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] data = {
                    rs.getString("column1"), // Your actual column names
                    rs.getString("column2"),
                    rs.getString("column3")
                };
                csvWriter.writeNext(data); // Write the CSV data to the response
            }

            csvWriter.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Logic for Handling SQL exception
        } finally {
            //Properly closing resources
            cm.closeResultSet(rs);
            cm.closeStatement(statement);
            cm.deallocateConnection(con);
        }
    }
}


This code won't work with the latest Java. Also it's too buggy to post here. Read my comment above.
